# How to direct clicks based on the original click and then a selection

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

Im failing to find the correct terms for what I'm looking to do. I'm not a coder but I can get it done If I get pointed in the correct direction.

I have a network of sites. A main website, a blog, and 3 different woocom stores (international legal reasons all 3 need to be completely separated) I need to be able post a link to a product,let's say "www.--.com/product-x", on the main site the blog or a stand alone link in maybe a Facebook post. Once a potential customer clicks on that link I want them to be sent to a region select page of which there are 3 options. But I don't want them to just be sent to the landing for the woocom store of there selection I want them to be sent to "na.--.com/product-x" or "eu.--.com/product-x"

If it were just 4 or 5 products I would just duplicate the region select page but this isn't realistic. I'd like to compile the "/product-x" part of the URL from where they clicked from,and the "na." And "eu." Part of the URL from there selection.

I'm willing to do some possibly cumbersome .htaccess upkeep or add the pathways individually each time a new product link gets made of that keeps things simpler but aibjust don't want 100 region select pages.

I am aware of Geo-redirects but I'm just not there yet. I for the world can not type the correct thing into Google to find any help on this, and it's not conceivable to me that this is an original idea.

What is this called?